# PD and Current path in CROs

Tags: electrostatics

I have few questions regarding CROs .
1 I want to know that how cathode grid and pre accelerating and accelerating grid are higly charge .?
2 They are connected to same battery or different batteries or how they develope charges??
3 They work like a capicator?
4 where do these electrons goes after hitting flourcent screen or how they complete circuit .

Comment: Comment to the post (v1): Consider to spell out acronyms.

Answer (score 0):

1) High voltage power supplies.

2) No batteries. High voltage power supplies.

3) Yes, but very, very small ones. And the capacitive effects do not affect their performance as electron accelerators.

4) The electrons are absorbed, and the energy of collision causes fluorescence. Electrons in, light out.

Comment: 4 The fluorescent screen is made conducting and there is a return path for the electrons.